# How to copy the results of a find command in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a find command which returns two files. Is there anyway of then copying those files to another directory? My find command is below if that will help.

```
find "$TEST" -iname "DTWD_????.JPG" -printf "%f\n"
```

New to linux, thanks.

Comment: This has **absolutely** nothing to do with sql in any way.

Comment: Look for questions about `find` on this site. There are many of them and many of them deal with how to perform actions on the resulting files.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake, I have changed them now and I have too but none of them really answer my question. I know how to redirect them into a new file, but not to a new directory.

Comment: You mean you can redirect the output into a file's contents. Sure. But that's not what you want to do. Look around again. There are a number of ways to operate on the output from find depending on what you want to do.

Comment: As I have already said, I have been looking for some time now, thus I am creating a question. If you don't have helpful advice/tips, then I would appreciate it if you didn't comment.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind is a good place to start to understand, well, `find`.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20781936/258523) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6648112/258523) for example from the first page of search results for `shell find move`. I'm sure there are others as well.

Comment: ...and by the way -- "if you can't tell me something I want to hear, please don't comment" isn't a good way to get a feel for the culture when using a new site for the first time. People who tell you you're doing something wrong are often (hopefully!) doing so such that you can avoid making the same mistake again.

Comment: Already said this, those answers aren't helping me hence why I created a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the -exec argument

```
find "$TEST" -iname "DTWD_????.JPG" -printf "%f\n" -exec mv -t '/home' '{}' +
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will give this a go.

Comment: Okay @cv28, accept my answer if it meets your needs

Comment: As an aside, on systems with GNU `mv`, one can use `-exec mv -t /home '{}' +` instead, which is considerably more efficient (calling `mv` only as many times as necessary, as opposed to once per file).

Comment: Hi @LuisDaniel, the script runs without error, but files have not copied into directory. I am using the ls command to check.

Comment: @cv28 are you sure that your find command found some file... and add to my solution what Charles Duffy mentioned above.

Comment: check also, if you has permission to write on your target directory

Comment: Hello, @LuisDaniel, script runs with no errors but files still not copied, used 'chmod u+x' to give myself write permissions but still nothing.

Comment: what is your output por command `find "$TEST" -iname "DTWD_????.JPG" -printf "%f\n"` ? perhaps you must remove the printf statement.

Comment: 'mv: accessing '~root/my-documents/"$2"': No such file or directory. "$2" is user argument and it does return file names. Removing -printf did not help unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, got it now. I just removed the " ' " on both ends of the target folder name. Thanks a lot for your help with this.